# Pointer referencing: What's the difference between pointer referencing in number 1 and 2.

Tags: c, pointers

why the first one works fine while second one shows error.
1.

```
char *reverse(char *ara)
{
    char *ptr1=ara,*ptr2=ara;


}
```

2.

```
char *reverse(char *ara)
{
    char *ptr1,*ptr2;
    *ptr1=ara,*ptr2=ara;

}
```

where main function looks like this

```
int main()
{
    char ara[100]="Programming";
    reverse(ara);
}
```

Comment: Because first is assigning the value to pointers and the second one - to pointees.

Comment: If you have a pointer `ptr`, and then *dereference* it with `*` (i.e `*ptr`) what do you get then? Not to be condescending but I recommend you go find a good text book or tutorial about pointers and read it.

Comment: In the *declarations* of `ptr1` and `ptr2`, the `*` characters are part of the declared types of those identifiers.  In an executable statement they are the dereferencing operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is equivalent to:

```
char *ptr1;
char *ptr2;
ptr1 = ara; // ptr1 points to the same place as ara
ptr2 = ara; // ptr2 points to the same place as ara
```

while the second is equivalent to:

```
char *ptr1;
char *ptr2;
*ptr1 = ara; // Problems
*ptr2 = ara; // Problems
```

Problem 1:

Those lines are compile time problems since `*ptr1` and `*ptr2` evaluate to `char` while the type they are being assigned to is `char*`.

Problem 2:

If the compiler were to ignore the error, you will run into run time error since neither `ptr1` nor `ptr2` point to anything valid and you are using `*ptr1` or `*ptr2` to assign values to.

Answer (score 0):

A declaration such as `char *ptr1;`, says `*ptr1` is a `char`, meaning `ptr1` is a pointer to a `char`.

When the declaration includes initialization, as in `char *ptr1 = ara;`, it means `ptr1`, which is a pointer to `char`, is initialized with the value `ara`.

In an assignment such as `*ptr1 = ara`, `*ptr1` means the thing that `ptr1` points to. So this assignment is attempting to assign the value `ara`, which is a pointer to `char`, to the `char` that `ptr1` points to. Your compiler complains about this because a `char` is not a suitable destination for a pointer to `char`.

You should be clear about how names look in declarations and how they look in expressions. In a declaration, the name is used with operators to show an example of how it will be used. For example, `char foo()` says `foo` will be used as a function, so it is a function that returns a `char`, and `char foo[]` says `foo` will be used as an array, so it is an array of `char`.

When you use an identifier the same way it appears in a declaration, it forms an expression with the declared type. So, after the declaration `char *ptr1`, the expression `*ptr1` is a `char`. The actual pointer to a `char` that was declared is `ptr1`, not `*ptr1`.

When initialization appears in a declaration, it initializes the declared object (`ptr1`), not the example expression in the declaration (not `*ptr1`).